# Create React App - Debugging - Import Variables Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, es6-modules

Using the standard *Create React App* setup, when I debug in Chrome my `import {moduleA} from './lib'` variables are undefined in the debugger (eg: mouse hover over variable produces nothing; variable is not listed in `locals`, can't access in console), but the runtime can access it (ie `console.log(moduleA)` prints the module object). Is there a way to get access to them in the debugger?

### Research

- Looks like it might have something to do with how Babel compiles modules. Not sure why it doesn't produce source maps though? Seems like I could `eject` the app and try to replace all Babel usage with Typescript. But still strikes me as odd that this is even an issue and makes me suspicious I'm missing something obvious.

### Example

`console.log(moduleA)` will log the module to the console, but `moduleA` does not exist in locals nor can it be accessed in the console.

[image: moduleA console logging works]

Guessing that webpack renames the `import {moduleA} from './lib';` to `_lib__WEBPACK...`, but confused why there isn't some sort of source map for this back to import variable `moduleA`?

[image: module missing in locals]

`moduleA` import variable also unavailable in console

[image: module not available in console]

#### Angular Reference

This seems to work in Angular (using just `ng new` and adding and importing a `lib.ts`, not sure what the difference is:
[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161123/es6-module-import-is-not-defined-during-debugger - but the answer seems to be "use the webpack module name and assign it to your variable name". I was hoping to have it work directly (like the Angular example).

Comment: Related, but no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016317/imported-variable-works-but-is-not-defined-when-accessed-in-debugger-within-sam

Answer (score 1):

You might have a circular dependency, as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240717/10246496). You should try using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin) to detect circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue a while back, I switched from CreateReactApp to Vite(which doesn't use webpack) and it was fixed. If you don't get any solution and if its a new project then try switching to [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/).